# Drupal 7.x: how to apply styles to RSS feed in node?

Tags: php, css, drupal, rss

How to apply CSS style to RSS feed items in node? Drupal 7.x, I am using Feeds module to import RSS feeds and create news items nodes. I want apply some CSS style to display feed items, reduce width of news container and add borders around the news items. Is it possible to apply style to RSS feed items in node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Dirty:** you can edit the page and add html `<style>` elements in the node, and this is very easy, but obviously not a great way to manage style

**Clean:** find the stylesheets that Drupal references (using Google chrome right click on the element you wish to edit, hit "Inspect Element" and to the right will be the element's style properties as well as the file where they came from. Navigate to this file and you can add the style attributes as you wish

Comment: will the CSS styles affect the feed items only or affect all content types?

Comment: You will have to inspect the elements that you wish to style and use their classes/IDs/element types to ensure that you are only targeting them with your new style definitions